# How to hide all items except the active branch on click - menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I'd like to open one node on click, and remove is-active class from others items.

at this point there is a lot of space taken up after opening a few menu items. I would like only one node to be open at a time. So it needs the is-active class to be removed from the previous sub-item after switching to another sub-item

The red square opens the item.. - Could you please help me?

```js
 const nav = document.querySelector('.menu-primary');

// const navElement = nav.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');

const navElementIcon = nav.querySelectorAll('.js-navigation-arrow');

// console.log(navElesment);

navElementIcon.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let elementParent = element.closest('.menu-item-has-children');


        if (elementParent.classList.contains('is-active')) {
            elementParent.classList.remove('is-active');
        } else {
            elementParent.classList.add('is-active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.menu-primary a {
  margin-right: 30px !important;
}
.menu-primary > li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu-primary > li:first-child .menu-item a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.menu-primary > li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.menu-primary > li > .menu-item-icon {
  top: 7px;
}
.menu-primary > li .sub-menu {
  position: static;
  transform: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu-primary > li .sub-menu > .sub-menu__list > li > .sub-menu__child-list {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.menu-primary > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
.menu-primary a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu-item-icon {
  display: flex;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu-item.is-active > .sub-menu {
   display: block;
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.sub-menu__child-list {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.menu-item.is-active > .sub-menu__child-list {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-primary">
    <li id="menu-item-58084"
        class="col-1 menu-icon menu-icon-people menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-58084">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                <li id="menu-item-58085"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58085"><a
                        href="#nasz-zespol-psycholog-psychoterapeuta/">Child</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-58091"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-58091">
                    <a href="#">Nasze gabinety</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-58086"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58086"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Gocław</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58087"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58087"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Szczecin</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58088"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58088"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Ursynów</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58089"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58089"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Warszawa Centrum</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58090"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58090"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Wilanów</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-58092"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58092"><a href="#">Praca
                        dla psychoterapeuty</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-58093"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58093"><a
                        href="">Współpracują z nami</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-59230"
        class="col-3 menu-icon menu-icon-gender menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59230">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                <li id="menu-item-59231"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59231">
                    <a href="#">Sub item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59280"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59280"><a
                                href="#">Bezpłodność</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59233"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59233"><a
                                href="#">Depresja poporodowa</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59232"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59232">
                    <a href="#">Trudności w relacji z innymi</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59234"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59234"><a
                                href="#wypalenie-zawodowe/">Wypalenie zawodowe</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59235"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59235"><a
                                href="#niesmialosc/">Nieśmiałość</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59236"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59236"><a
                                href="#przemoc-w-relacji/">Przemoc w relacji</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59237"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59237"><a
                                href="#wspoluzaleznienie/">Współuzależnienie</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59238"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59238">
                    <a href="#">Trudności w relacji ze sobą</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59242"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59242"><a
                                href="#jak-podniesc-swoja-samoocene/">Niska samoocena</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59243"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59243"><a
                                href="#prokrastynacja/">Prokrastynacja</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59244"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59244"><a
                                href="#leczenie-depresji/">Depresja</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59247"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59247">
                    <a href="#">Dolegliwości psychiczne a zaburzenia hormonalne</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59249"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59249"><a
                                href="#pms-jak-poradzic-sobie-z-zespolem-napiecia-przedmiesiaczkowego/">PMS
                                napięcie przedmiesiączkowe</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59248"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59248"><a
                                href="#czym-jest-menopauza-jak-poradzic-sobie-z-jej-psychicznymi-objawami/">Menopauza</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59252"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-59252">
                    <a href="#abc-zaburzen-odzywiania/">Zaburzenia odżywiania</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59253"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59253"><a
                                href="#leczenie-ortoreksji/">Leczenie ortoreksji</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59254"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59254"><a
                                href="#leczenie-anoreksji/">Leczenie anoreksji</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59260"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59260">
                    <a href="#">Częste uzależnienia u kobiet</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59261"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59261"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-zakupow/">Uzależnienie od zakupów</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59262"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59262"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-pracy/">Uzależnienie od pracy</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59263"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59263"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-seksu/">Uzależnienie od seksu</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59264"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59264"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-lekow/">Uzależnienie od leków</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made two different approaches you can follow, they are described within the code below. I hope I was helpful.

```js
 const nav = document.querySelector('.menu-primary');

// const navElement = nav.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');

const navElementIcon = nav.querySelectorAll('.js-navigation-arrow');

// console.log(navElesment);

navElementIcon.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let elementParent = element.closest('.menu-item-has-children');

        if (elementParent.classList.contains('is-active')) {
            elementParent.classList.remove('is-active');
        } else {
            /*
                If you just want to close active items in the same
                level that the one you're opening, use the command below.
                Example: If you click About Us -> Nasze gabinety ->
                Contact -> About Us, the Nasze gabinety is going to
                be opened yet.
            */
            // Array.from(elementParent.parentElement.children)
            //     .forEach((menuItem) => menuItem.classList.remove('is-active'));

            /*
                If you want to close all active items, use the command below.
                Example: If you click About Us -> Nasze gabinety ->
                Contact -> About Us, the Nasze gabinety is going to
                be closed.
            */
            Array.from(elementParent.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.is-active'))
                .forEach((menuItem) => menuItem.classList.remove('is-active'));

            elementParent.classList.add('is-active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.menu-primary a {
  margin-right: 30px !important;
}
.menu-primary > li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu-primary > li:first-child .menu-item a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.menu-primary > li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.menu-primary > li > .menu-item-icon {
  top: 7px;
}
.menu-primary > li .sub-menu {
  position: static;
  transform: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu-primary > li .sub-menu > .sub-menu__list > li > .sub-menu__child-list {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.menu-primary > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
.menu-primary a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu-item-icon {
  display: flex;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu-item.is-active > .sub-menu {
   display: block;
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.sub-menu__child-list {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.menu-item.is-active > .sub-menu__child-list {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-primary">
    <li id="menu-item-58084"
        class="col-1 menu-icon menu-icon-people menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-58084">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                <li id="menu-item-58085"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58085"><a
                        href="#nasz-zespol-psycholog-psychoterapeuta/">Child</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-58091"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-58091">
                    <a href="#">Nasze gabinety</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-58086"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58086"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Gocław</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58087"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58087"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Szczecin</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58088"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58088"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Ursynów</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58089"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58089"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Warszawa Centrum</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-58090"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58090"><a
                                href="#">Gabinet Wilanów</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-58092"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58092"><a href="#">Praca
                        dla psychoterapeuty</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-58093"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58093"><a
                        href="">Współpracują z nami</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-59230"
        class="col-3 menu-icon menu-icon-gender menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59230">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                <li id="menu-item-59231"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59231">
                    <a href="#">Sub item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59280"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59280"><a
                                href="#">Bezpłodność</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59233"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59233"><a
                                href="#">Depresja poporodowa</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59232"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59232">
                    <a href="#">Trudności w relacji z innymi</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59234"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59234"><a
                                href="#wypalenie-zawodowe/">Wypalenie zawodowe</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59235"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59235"><a
                                href="#niesmialosc/">Nieśmiałość</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59236"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59236"><a
                                href="#przemoc-w-relacji/">Przemoc w relacji</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59237"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59237"><a
                                href="#wspoluzaleznienie/">Współuzależnienie</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59238"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59238">
                    <a href="#">Trudności w relacji ze sobą</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59242"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59242"><a
                                href="#jak-podniesc-swoja-samoocene/">Niska samoocena</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59243"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59243"><a
                                href="#prokrastynacja/">Prokrastynacja</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59244"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59244"><a
                                href="#leczenie-depresji/">Depresja</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59247"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59247">
                    <a href="#">Dolegliwości psychiczne a zaburzenia hormonalne</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59249"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59249"><a
                                href="#pms-jak-poradzic-sobie-z-zespolem-napiecia-przedmiesiaczkowego/">PMS
                                napięcie przedmiesiączkowe</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59248"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59248"><a
                                href="#czym-jest-menopauza-jak-poradzic-sobie-z-jej-psychicznymi-objawami/">Menopauza</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59252"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-59252">
                    <a href="#abc-zaburzen-odzywiania/">Zaburzenia odżywiania</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59253"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59253"><a
                                href="#leczenie-ortoreksji/">Leczenie ortoreksji</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59254"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59254"><a
                                href="#leczenie-anoreksji/">Leczenie anoreksji</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59260"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-59260">
                    <a href="#">Częste uzależnienia u kobiet</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu__child-list">
                        <li id="menu-item-59261"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59261"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-zakupow/">Uzależnienie od zakupów</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59262"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-59262"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-pracy/">Uzależnienie od pracy</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59263"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59263"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-seksu/">Uzależnienie od seksu</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-59264"
                            class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59264"><a
                                href="#uzaleznienie-od-lekow/">Uzależnienie od leków</a></li>
                    </ul><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><span class="icon icon-arrow menu-item-icon js-navigation-arrow"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```